# Irreducible and recurrent Markov chain - theorem notation question

Tags: stochastic-processes, notation, markov-chains, markov-process

In [J. R. Norris] Markov Chains (Cambridge Series in Statistical and Probabilistic Mathematics) (2009), page 35, Theorem 1.7.5 says:

[image]

In (ii), does it mean $\gamma^k$ is notation for $\gamma^k_i$ over all $i \in I$ or for some fixed arbitrary $i \in I$?

I think it's the latter but I just want to make sure that I'm interpreting this nice and compact way of writing it correctly.

Comment: Your first interpretation is correct: for example if $I = \{1,2,3\}$, then $\gamma^k$ is short for $(\gamma^k_1,\gamma^k_2,\gamma^k_3)$.

Comment: @angryavian Looking ahead at the proof it seems that this is indeed correct. So another way to write this in slightly more familiar notation (to me) would be $(\gamma^k_i)_{i \in I}$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is another way it is notated.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks for the confirmation! If you want, please add this as an answer so that I can accept it as one and close this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first interpretation is correct: for example if $I=\{1,2,3\}$, then $\gamma^k$ is short for $(\gamma_1^k,\gamma_2^k,\gamma_3^k)$. Another way this is notated is $(\gamma_i^k)_{i \in I}$.